# Regex, optionally capture 3 groups at the end of a string

Tags: regex

I have a string which looks like the following:

```
VAL "foo"
VAL2 "bar"
VAL3 "barbar"
OPTIONALVAL "optionalvalue"
SPECIALVAL "optionalval"
```

Where `OPTIONALVAL` is optional (may or may not appear) and if it appears then it has a value pair in the second column (`"optionalvalue"` in the example), and `SPECIALVAL` is also optional, but it has no paired value in the second column.

Here is my regex, but it doesn't match anything if `OPTIONALVAL` is missing (should match all the others which are not missing)!

```
 "^[[:space:]]*"
 "(VAL)[[:space:]]*\"(.*)\"[[:space:]]*"
 "(VAL2)[[:space:]]*\"(.*)\"[[:space:]]*"
 "(VAL3)[[:space:]]*\"(.*)\"[[:space:]]*"
 "(OPTIONALVAL)?[[:space:]]*\"(?(7)(.*))\"[[:space:]]*"; // conditional capture
 "(SPECIALVAL)?[[:space:]]*";
```

What am I doing wrong? (I am using Boost regex, `:space:` should be equivalent to the space character.

Comment: What regex engine are you using?

Comment: @Vallentin the default from <boost/regex.hpp> so Perl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your *conditional capture*, you can do something like `(?:xyz)?` where `xyz` is the conditional pattern.

```
VAL\s*"(.*?)"\s*
VAL2\s*"(.*?)"\s*
VAL3\s*"(.*?)"\s*
(?:OPTIONALVAL\s*"(.*?)"\s*)?
SPECIALVAL
```

[**Live preview**](https://regex101.com/r/6l4Zy5/1)

*Note that the live preview has the extended flag enabled, to ignore those newlines.*

As your question reflects that you want to capture `VAL`, etc. Then you of course need to surround them with parenthesis.

The thing to notice, is that whether *conditional capture* is present or not. All the capture groups will still remain the same index-wise.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however if OPTIONALVAL and/or SPECIALVAL is present then I also want to capture them as well. I'm fiddling with your regex and I am not getting matches for them for some reason. I.e. I want to capture everything that is present in the first column and second column.

Comment: You just need to surround them with parenthesis. [Here's an extremely colorful live preview.](https://regex101.com/r/6l4Zy5/2)